# Why calling a function from a webapp url is not working in this context?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The basic flow is as follows:

1. User ticks a checkbox in `file B`;
2. The url gets accessed;
3. Based on the key parameters passed, it runs a function in `file A`;
4. This function processes a dataset and populates some tabs in `file B`.

The issue I am finding is that if I do it by pasting the url in the address bar, it works, but not when I run on edit basis. Note that the function running on edit is based on an `installable trigger`, with the authorization granted for `UrlFetchApp`.
It stops at the pop-up setup `Something went wrong and the item's data couldn't be imported. Check the item in the Orders file and try it again`

This is the code run in `file B`:

```
function editEvents(e) {
  const activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetName = activeSheet.getName();

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const value = e.range.getValue();
  const sheetHeaders = activeSheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  if (sheetName === "Summary") {
    const checkBoxCol = sheetHeaders.indexOf(pullDataColName);
    const systemIdCol = sheetHeaders.indexOf(systemIdColName);
    const systemId = activeSheet.getRange(row, systemIdCol + 1).getValue();

    if (value === true && systemId !== "") {
      const webAppBaseUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/ID/exec";
      const queryParameter = "?key=data" + "-" + systemId;
      const webAppUrl = webAppBaseUrl + queryParameter;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(webAppUrl))

      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl);
      const content = response.getResponseCode();

      if (content === 200) {
        const responseBody = response.getContentText();
        if (responseBody === 'ok') {
          return;
        } else {
          activeSheet.getRange(row, checkBoxCol + 1).clearContent();
          Browser.msgBox("Something went wrong and the item's data couldn't be imported. Check the item in the Orders file and try it again.");
          return;
        }
      } else {
        Logger.log("Error: " + response.getResponseCode() + " - " + response.getContentText());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `doGet()` function:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const urlKey = e.parameter.key.toString().split('-');
  let dataType = urlKey[0];
  const systemId = urlKey[1];
  const selectedRow = null; //Will need it for a criteria check within sendItemsToProductionFiles()

  if (dataType == 'data'  && systemId !== '') {
    sendItemsToProductionFiles(dataType, selectedRow, systemId);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('ok');
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Parameters not passed');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your setting of Web Apps? First, can you provide the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, `editEvents` and `doGet` are put into the same Google Apps Script project or different projects? First, I would like to correctly understand your situation.

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike! Execute as Me and Anyone within the domain can access it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your Google Apps Script project is included in an account of Google Workspace? And, `editEvents` and `doGet` are put into the same Google Apps Script project or different projects?

Comment: This is in a Google Workspace and the functions are in different spreadsheets, @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `the functions are in different spreadsheets`, in this case, the owner of both Google Apps Script projects is the same account?

Comment: Correct. Both files are owned by me and I have setup the installable trigger, @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize. And, when you modify the function `editEvents`, please reinstall the OnEdit trigger to the function `editEvents`. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion in the comment, I understood your situation as follows.

- Your account is included in Google Workspace.
- `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:` are `Me` and `Anyone within the domain can access it`, respectively.
- Functions `editEvents` and `doGet` are put into 2 Google Apps Script projects.
- You are the owner of those 2 Google Apps Script projects.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the access token is included in the request header.

#### From:

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl);
```

#### To:

```
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // Please don't remove this comment line.
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
```

- This comment line of `// DriveApp.getFiles();` is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly". This scope is used for requesting Web Apps. So please don't remove this comment line.

#### Note:

- **Before you test this script, please reinstall the OnEdit trigger to the function `editEvents`. By this, the new scope is added.**
- Also, just in case, please redeploy your Web Apps and confirm the URL of the Web Apps again.
- By the way, in this modification, it supposes that your function `sendItemsToProductionFiles` works fine. Please be careful about this.

Comment: This was right on - AGAIN! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.